# HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am fetching comments on a youtube video using YouTube's Data API, after getting a certain number(~2000) of comments by paginating using the 'pageToken' all of a sudden i start receiving following error :

> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads returned "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the `commentThread` resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.">

this is the piece of code in Python I am using to make request iteratively:

```
api_response = self.youtube_data_api_session.commentThreads().list(                                                                part="snippet,replies",                                                                videoId=video_id,                                                                order="relevance",
pageToken= next_page_token,
maxResults=100
).execute()
```

So, I have 2 questions :

1. If the request format was wrong why it didn't failed in the first iteration ?
2. If the request format is right, how to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 1):

> If the request format was wrong why it didn't failed in the first iteration ?

The initial request probably worked just fine.  However as you are paging you are actually making additional requests.  If one of those fails then you will not be able to get additional data.

> If the request format is right, how to avoid this error ?

Format looks fine to me there is really no way to fix this as you are just paging.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for the response. But is there nothing that can be done to fix this ? Because this is very strange behavior of this API, I also tried with sleep time upto 20 minutes between each page request, for first few pages it works fine but then again I get this error.

Comment: Note just try again.  I am assuming that you haven't changed the body of the request so there should be nothing you are doing wrong on your side.    Assuming that you are fetching the next rows right away and not waiting to long it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced the same issue, I fixed it by changing order from `relevance` to `time`.

It might not help OP because `order` wasn't specified in the original code and ordering by `time` is a default behavior. Nevertheless, this could be useful for other readers.

When using `order='relevance'`, the HTTP 400 was thrown either when the request takes slightly longer than 4000ms or when passing a certain page (in my case, page 17 with `maxResults=100`).

It could be due to how YouTube APIs handle nextPageToken for `order='relevance'`. Notice how nextPageToken and response time constantly increase in the logs below.

```
Page: 1, nextPageToken length: 1848, response time: 475ms
Page: 2, nextPageToken length: 2376, response time: 996ms
Page: 3, nextPageToken length: 2884, response time: 922ms
Page: 4, nextPageToken length: 3404, response time: 1370ms
Page: 5, nextPageToken length: 4068, response time: 1513ms
Page: 6, nextPageToken length: 4396, response time: 1644ms
Page: 7, nextPageToken length: 4556, response time: 2121ms
Page: 8, nextPageToken length: 5232, response time: 2302ms
Page: 9, nextPageToken length: 5564, response time: 2161ms
Page: 10, nextPageToken length: 5732, response time: 2702ms
Page: 11, nextPageToken length: 6412, response time: 2749ms
Page: 12, nextPageToken length: 6748, response time: 3214ms
Page: 13, nextPageToken length: 6888, response time: 3352ms
Error fetching comments HTTP 400, response time 4191ms, retrying
Page: 14, nextPageToken length: 7552, response time: 2944ms
Page: 15, nextPageToken length: 7860, response time: 3884ms
Page: 16, nextPageToken length: 8044, response time: 4148ms
Error fetching comments HTTP 400, response time 114ms, retrying
Error fetching comments HTTP 400, response time 111ms, retrying
Error fetching comments HTTP 400, response time 113ms, retrying
Error fetching comments HTTP 400, response time 111ms, retrying
Error fetching comments HTTP 400, response time 103ms, retrying
Error fetching comments HTTP 400, response time 102ms, retrying
```

In contrast, when ordering by time, nextPageToken has a length of up to 200 characters and response times are quite stable.